# I have copied my path and now I can't alter its stroke size etc

Tags: adobe-photoshop, path

[image]

I drew a path. But on the upper menu, right next to the green stroke colour symbol, there is normally the option to change the stroke size. But I can not click there for unknown reasons. What do I have to change??

Comment: Copied from where to where? Which menu is 'black'? A screenshot or two might help us to answer your question.

Comment: I literally copied it on the exact same position. The Menu is the bar on top where the "Form" can be altered. Like Thickness in px etc.

Comment: Still not very clear, but I suspect that you are getting confused between 'paths' and 'shape paths'. Paths don't have fills and strokes, shapes do.

Comment: Turns out that's what happened! But when I rastered it - can I change it back to a smart shape? I think that didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like what you have done is apply a STROKE to a PATH. This is a one shot operation and once the stroke has been rendered you are not able to change the colour, weight, etc in the way that you are expecting. The path should still be in the paths palette so you can reapply a new stroke or fill with different settings if you need to.

The best way to achieve the result that you are looking for is to either use SHAPES in Photoshop (these are best suited to primitive shapes and lines, but can be used for more complex shapes) or to use SMART OBJECTS (assuming that you also have Illustrator). This will allow you to build your design using vector elements that retain their editablity in the way that you need.